# What happened to Kaa?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-jungle-book-2016

In [The Jungle Book](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3040964/), we see [Kaa just about to eat Mowgli](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r2SSEaWCAi0). But [Baloo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6YPEaWPhsCY) arrives just in time and he and attacks Kaa, saving Mowgli.

**Do we know if Kaa survives the attack?** The movie is quite dark at times and doesn't shy away from killing off characters, so I'm curious to know if Baloo actually kills Kaa during their battle.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear whether Kaa survived the attack, but in my opinion, I don't think Baloo killed [Kaa](http://villains.wikia.com/wiki/Kaa_(The_Jungle_Book_2016)), because Kaa is heard singing her song "[Trust in me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trust_in_Me_(The_Python%27s_Song))" in the end credits, so my guess is, she survived the fight. I also found this on [this source](http://villains.wikia.com/wiki/Kaa_(The_Jungle_Book_2016)):

> Kaa isn't seen again for the rest of the film; it is unknown if Baloo
>   killed her or she went away and never came back. During the end
>   credits however, she is heard singing her song, "Trust in Me".

Comment: The quote doesn't really add anything to your answer; it just repeats it. Besides, I don't think that Villains Wikia is an authoritative source.